# Multiple interfaces with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

Im building a game with VB.NET

I designed the core of the game in form1 window

But now I need menus. How can I implement this without having 5 or so windows that I show() and hide() ? Doing that slows it down a lot and uses lots of memory. I tried tabs, but I don't want the tabs to appear, just switch. Whats the best way to implement multiple interfaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one menustrip with all toolstripmenuitems for all five menus.

Make all the toolstripmenuitems invisible (.visible = false) except for those for the "current menu." When you make a toolstripmenuitem invisible, all its subitems also disappear and that menu item is inaccessible.

When you change "menus", you can make another set of toolstripmenuitems visible. You'll only have one menu, but you can make it look like you have 5.